# Changing config file using msdeploy command line

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

I have managed to get the deployment package (using msbuild) as shown in below image

[image: Folder structure for my deployment package]

TRANSFORM_CONFIGS folder contains different web.config files based on the environment [lab/test/live] and NimTestWebApp.zip is the deployment package created using

```
msbuild BuildDeployWebApp/BuildDeployWebApp.csproj /t:package /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageLocation=C:\Temp\DeployPackage\TestWebApp.zip
```

All other files are standard files created while building a deployment package.

Now what I am looking forward to is a way by which when I deploy the package to particular environment, I can replace the particular config files. Can I use SetParameters.xml file or any sort of manifest file to achieve my goal? OR should I use command line argument passing way? Could you please provide me robust way to get  it done